Subsequent PDF Signature Invalidates Previous Signature
I'm encountering an issue with applying multiple digital signatures to a PDF file generated using an updated version of the Go package github.com/digitorus/pdfsign.
When viewing the document in Adobe Acrobat, the first signature becomes invalidated after subsequent signatures are added.

The first signature is applied and validates successfully.
When a subsequent signature is added, the first signature becomes invalidated (shows as "Invalid" in Acrobat).
Interestingly, each signature validates individually when checked separately.

Only the last signature validates correctly:
Signatures
When checking the first signature using "View Signed Version" in Acrobat, that signature also validates correctly:
View Signed Version
Checking the original or signed document for PDF syntax issues using Adobe Acrobat Preflight does not detect any issues.
Preflight
Based on this similar issue, it seems that when the first signature was applied, the document may have been saved with a minor error. As a result, Adobe Acrobat seems to consider each signature in the PDF broken, except the signature of the full (latest) document.
The issue highlighted above is caused by a segmented xref table, but that is not the case here, as I do not have a segmented xref table. Also, when recreating the entire xref table from scratch, I encounter the same problem.
I suspect there may be another issue with the incremental update.
The incremental update(s) appended to the PDF document looks like:

10 0 obj
<< /Type /Annot /Subtype /Widget /Rect [0 0 0 0] /P 5 0 R /F 132 /FT /Sig /T (Signature10) /Ff 0 /V 12 0 R >>
endobj
11 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R /AcroForm << /Fields [7 0 R 10 0 R] /NeedAppearances false /SigFlags 3 /Perms << /UR 12 0 R >> >> >>
endobj
12 0 obj
<< /Type /Sig /Filter /Adobe.PPKLite /SubFilter /adbe.pkcs7.detached /ByteRange [0 5000 7870 414]                   /Contents<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> /TransformMethod /FieldMDP /TransformParams << /Type /TransformParams /Fields [<< /Type /SigFieldLock /Action /All >>] /V /1.2 >> /Name (Jane 2 Doe) /Location (Anywhere) /Reason (Approval Signature 2) /ContactInfo (None) /M (D:20241113121510+01'00') >>
endobj
xref
10 3
0000004592 00000 n 
0000004718 00000 n 
0000004866 00000 n 
trailer
<<
    /Root 11 0 R
    /Prev 4441
    /Size 13
>>
startxref
8131
%%EOF

Files

Source file small.pdf
Signed file SignPDFWithTwoApproval_2_556137430.pdf


The signature field values have some strange entries in view to the TransformMethod:
/TransformMethod /FieldMDP 
/TransformParams << 
    /Type /TransformParams 
    /Fields [
        << 
            /Type /SigFieldLock 
            /Action /All 
        >>
    ] 
    /V /1.2 
>>

The /Fields value is invalid. It looks like a mix of TransformParams for the FieldMDP transform method and Lock entries of a signature field.
Also there's an UR key in the documents Perms dictionary referencing the last signature (this is also updated/changed by both signatures). But: There's no UR key for a permissions dictionary defined in the PDF specification.
Maybe these issues will let the validation engine fail.

Indeed, these appear to be the main issues. Just one other possible issue: By using a FieldMDP transform on the first signature at all, you may make Acrobat think that the document is subject to the stricter rules used for certified documents. These in particular would disallow addition of new signature fields (only filling in existing, empty signature fields would be allowed, if at all). Thus, your second signature would be invalid as it adds a new field. (I haven't tested this with correct transforms yet, though, so this is a mere assumption.) BTW locking all fields may include new ones.

Signing the first signed revision with Acrobat ends in "all signatures are valid" - which makes me guessing that the update of the Perms dictionary is the main cause (for Acrobat). But all other things should be solved, too!

Removin the Perms from the AcroForm entry in the document catalog dictionary solved the problem. There is no Perms defined in the AcroForm in table 224 of ISO 32000-2:2020. Does anyone know a good validator that woud report on such things?

@vanbroup "Removin the Perms from the AcroForm entry in the document catalog dictionary solved the problem." - Beware, the other issues mentioned can cause other validators to reject your signature as invalid, and rightly so! Here Acrobat appears to be very lax in signature related contexts.
